# Inequality between the real and imaginary part of a complex

Tags: complex-numbers

Let S be the area of ​​the region formed by all affixes z(x,y)= x+yi with i the imaginary unit of complex numbers that satisfy the inequality Re($\frac{z+1}{z+2}$) $\le$ Im($\frac{z+1}{z+2}$). So the value of S is?

My question is, how can I relate the inequality and condition it to find the area of ​​the plane that validates the relationship?

The answer is $\pi/2$, the author's suggestion is to use analytical geometry to solve the problem, trying to arrive at the radius of a circle.

Comment: What did you tried? and [see[(https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: I updated my topic with some information

Comment: Hint: the question is asking about the region in the domain $\Bbb C$ whose image under the function $z\mapsto\frac{z+1}{z+2}$ is in the half-plane $\{\Re w\le\Im w\}$. Can you use what you know about fractional linear transformations to find that region exactly, and then calculate its area?

Comment: @GregMartin Are you referring to the Mobius Transform? I couldn't come up with an algebraic answer. But thinking geometrically, there is a circle of radius 1 that is the area between cis(45) and cis (225) which is a region that gives Re(z)<=Im(z).